# excel change background when gender age and value cell better than other sheet

Tags: excel, match

I have a scoresheet with the following headers:

```
name surname gender age resultmission 1 2 3 4
```

And I have a standard sheet with the following headers:

```
gender age mission 1 2 3 4
```

I now want a cell conditional where it matches the scoresheet gender and age and if the value in scoresheet time is better than in the standard sheet it colors green. 
So scoresheet C2 and D2 have to match the row on standard sheet A and B. Then on the standard sheet the J value tells me the norm like 22.0  and on scoresheet the I value must be less or equal to J.

I tried Vlookup Index Match and an If statement but nothing seems to work. Does anybody have a quick solution how to do this?

some images of my excel only the best result wil count so we put that in the 1 and will later hide the extra not red arrow column.
[normsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUH7Q.jpg)

[resultsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCZrG.jpg)

Comment: Could you please paste some sample data? With just the column headers you have posted, this quesiton is very difficult to follow

Comment: You might have to write a macro rather than the vlookup or other excel formulas.

Comment: @Draken just added them

Comment: @Animesh What ever work best. I just want to save me the human compare error on 72 to 80 rows and 4 or 5 sportexercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to write a `VLOOKUP()` to get the `norm` value.  Then, compare it against the user's score using an `IF()` statement.  The `IF()` statement values should return `TRUE` and `FALSE`, so we can apply `conditional formatting` to it to change the cell fill to green.

Here's my simple example:

[image: Conditional Formatting using VLOOKUP and IF functions]

**HOW IT WORKS**

- Create a `Helper Column` on the standard sheet to `Concatenate()` Gender and Age
- To the right of the first score on the `Score Sheet`, write the `VLOOKUP()` formula to get the `Norm` value from the `Standard Sheet` (H3).
- In the same formula, add the `IF()` function by wrapping it around the `VLOOKUP()` by comparing the user's `Result` to the `Norm` result.  If the user's `result` is less than or equal to (<=) the `Norm`, then the formula should return TRUE, otherwise FALSE.
- Copy this formula down and verify it is evaluating correctly against other users.
- Select the first cell where the formula is typed and copy it (H3)... JUST THE TEXT, not the cell.  Then, select the full range of results (E3:E4) - must select top down.
- Go to Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
- Paste the formula as shown and `Format` the fill to be green.

Comment: I think this brings me pretty close to the solution of my puzzel. I will try this out. problem i have is that we have some other layout.

Name| surname | Gender | Age | Shuttlerun | 5 x 5 | stairwalk | Pylonwalk | etc |

Comment: I now have this formula but it gives an error
=IF(+'GROEP 1 RESULTAAT'!F2 <= Vlookup('GROEP 1 RESULTAAT'!C2:D2;NORMEN!A3:B24;NORMEN!E3:E24,3,FALSE),TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: With your example and a little tweaking i resolved my issue
=ALS(I2 <= VERT.ZOEKEN(D2;ALS(C2="M";$Q$41:$R$51;$Q$52:$R$62);2;ONWAAR);WAAR;ONWAAR)

Stupid dutch version. =IF(I2<= VLOOKUP(D2,IF(C2='M',$Q$41:$R$51,$Q$52:$R$62),2,FALSE),TRUE,FALSE)

And i had to copy the Normen page into the result page. Because otherwise it did not work on conditional formatting.